# PHP in Eclipse/PDT on Mac - posix_getpwuid not found

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt

Anyone has an idea why the following can happen:
PHP installed with mac ports `(php5, v. 5.3.6)` as `/opt/local/bin/php` can run posix functions fine, and `phpinfo()` shows `posix` installed.  But when I run a script with `posix_getpwuid` in Eclipse/PDT, it complains:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function posix_getpwuid() in <filename>`

Do I need to add something to the "PHP Libraries" setting in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using php 5.3+.

posix_getpwuid() is a part of POSIX.

"As of PHP 5.3.0 [POSIX] extension is deprecated, calling any function provided by this extension will issue an E_DEPRECATED notice."

more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.regex.php

Solutions:

1. use php 5.2
2. install POSIX extension
3. if posix_getpwuid() is only problem problem you have with POSIX, try function offered by "martin at arp242 dot net" - look for it here: 
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwuid.php